# extract sub string

Tags: erlang

I develop this function in erlang :

```
get_user_cin_by_token(Token) ->
    Q = qlc:q([{X#person.idcard} || X <- mnesia:table(person),
                X#person.token =:= Token]),
    case do(Q) of
        [H] ->
            {ok, H};
        [] ->
            {error, notfound}
    end.
```

this is an example of result when I execute this function :

```
{ok,{"07049200"}}
```

my goal is to disply just "07049200" without {}

I test with this function  :

```
test3()->

    case get_user_cin_by_token("93090612") of
        {ok, H}-> G=string:substr(H, 2, length(H)-1),
         io:format("~s~n",[G]);
        {error, notfound}->io:format("error")
end.
```

but this error is displyed :

```
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  length/1
        called as length({"07049200"})
```

Comment: Rather than having `{X#person.idcard}` in your QLC query, try using `X#person.idcard` so it doesn't get wrapped in a single-element tuple.

Comment: This is definitely the easiest solution to the problem. This wrapping totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

`{"07049200"}` is not a string; it's a tuple. Hence, you can "unpack" it by pattern matching: `{H} = {"07049200"}` will result in `H=07049200`.

In your original code you can do:

```
get_user_cin_by_token(Token) ->
    Q = qlc:q([{X#person.idcard} || X <- mnesia:table(person),
                X#person.token =:= Token]),
    case do(Q) of
        [{H}] ->
            {ok, H};
        [] ->
            {error, notfound}
    end.
```

Comment: I use your code  and I test with this code :

   it displys :

07049200

but I like to disply :

"07049200"

Comment: how to convert tuple to string

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
test3()->

    case get_user_cin_by_token("93090612") of
        {ok, {H}}-> io:format("\"~s\"~n",[H]);
        {error, notfound}->io:format("error")
end.
```